# Getting false positive alert with beacon exit / enter requin

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I have this iBeacon application in swift that perform some task when didExitRegion and didEnterRegion are called. Everything works well except I am getting false alert in a way that I am within the beacon range and all the sudden didExitRegion is getting fired and immediately in a few secs later didEnterRegion getting fired again. This happens when either the phone or the beacon hasn't moved or anything blocked the signals.
I read somewhere that this is a bug on the Apple side. Not sure how true this is, but what's the work around this? 
I was thinking to get the Alt, Lat every time the didExit is getting fired and compared with with the previous values or if there is a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think a potential solution could be to move the code currently inside of your didExitRegion method into a new new method. In didExitRegion start a timer for 5 seconds (or whatever you find to work best) inside to call the new method when it fires.

Then, if didEnterRegion is called while the timer is running, cancel the timer and return from didEnterRegion.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, it seems this is something that happens when your device loses the beacon's signal momentarily while still within range. My apps have sent me didEnterRegion notifications every 5 minutes when I've been sitting right next to the beacon. From what I've read, the performance of the app depends on the quality of the beacon as far as signal strength and signal frequency.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a problem with beacons that do not transmit frequently enough**.  A `didExitRegion` event will fire on iOS if no beacon packets have been detected in 30 seconds.  If a beacon is nearby and transmitting at the recommended 10 Hz, false positives are very, very rare.

**Many beacon manufacturers reduce transmission rates to save battery**, some making transmissions happen as seldom as every 5 seconds. **This leads to bad performance and false exits**.  Not all beacon packets transmitted get received due to radio noise and interference.  In practice, only 80-90% do.  With a beacon transmitting every 5 seconds, 6 missed packets in a row will cause an exit event.  This usually will not happen, but sometimes it will.

**The best solution is to configure the beacon to transmit more often**, ideally at 10 Hz or more.  If you get a beacon that lets you do this and make it transmit that often, false exits will be very, very rare.